# optim() stuck in a local minimum depending on scale

Tags: r, optimization

I am performing gaussian fits to a quite big number of 2D data points to test if they are (at least approxiamtely) following a gaussian curve. However I realized that when I am normalizing the y dimension to its maximum value I am getting a different result than when I am not. Here is an example with two vectors containing the y and x data respectively: (I am aware that those data are actually not following a gaussian distribution, which is the answer I would like to get via this test)

```
y = c(0, 4551.2783203125, 17204.81640625, 18554.16015625, 36956.65625, 
37979.30859375, 41470.2265625, 61240.8359375, 106161.9609375, 
87546.9375, 100634.7109375, 186276.765625, 221888.4375, 248687.84375, 
252164.890625, 343520.21875, 280060.625, 442446.15625, 424090.8125, 
442001.40625, 375247.46875, 458099.25, 607202.25, 452370.15625, 
361559.75, 481408.28125, 323888.53125, 500188.5625, 409107.1875, 
380734.96875, 312657.8125, 507054.5625, 423043.59375, 465331.0625, 
567257.375, 365184.125, 685140.5625, 459672.34375, 845416.5, 
455453.3125, 521206.03125, 613202.625, 477479.625, 579983.3125, 
760272.375, 514784.03125, 652986.5625, 413048.75, 533935.9375, 
686196.9375, 767804.9375, 665105.9375, 525717.6875, 631246.3125, 
545236.5, 621491.8125, 891600.8125, 870612.625, 570333.8125, 
562794.125, 680060.5625, 492349.90625, 492722.09375, 439363.0625, 
793801.1875, 629333.25, 697334.625, 441465.53125, 389707.71875, 
415848.25, 418587.0625, 527000.0625, 472959.34375, 508528.96875, 
679527.25, 655779.1875, 498504.0625, 376315.875, 429004.71875, 
328198.3125, 441643.53125, 406398.90625, 453388.03125, 349939.59375, 
348471.34375, 629093.5, 325516.03125, 285678.53125, 298847.8125, 
375509.875, 392465.15625, 367188.46875, 419100.9375, 311449.59375, 
260993.9375, 290824.6875, 236561.0625, 265879.5625, 379404.25, 
311229.6875, 307151.96875, 379062.46875, 280802.5, 457000.78125, 
260519.28125, 349163.875, 291823.40625, 260145.359375, 255300.3125, 
334640.84375, 306605.34375, 425454.46875, 257264.5, 220655.140625, 
223242.28125, 327066.5625, 300993.46875, 234662.15625, 262443.5, 
230376.796875, 227217.25, 236800.0625, 214616.421875, 260351.578125, 
226784.921875, 282392.28125, 200394.671875, 256462.5, 182574.59375, 
161353.78125, 165745.484375, 199003.859375, 175615.828125, 167471.859375, 
204727.078125, 207417.140625, 202296.46875, 183818.984375, 247653.640625, 
163297.9375, 171750.921875, 161632.78125, 201405.53125, 149500, 
123130.8125, 144252.359375, 173929.453125, 164804.953125, 144984.1875, 
140006.96875, 126611.0859375, 131078.140625, 222015.546875, 124387.859375, 
112429.4453125, 185341.9375, 83172.6640625, 142822.765625, 131457.234375, 
122272.4921875, 99884.0546875, 128589.4765625, 110691.6328125
)

x = c(7.99422121047974, 7.99860048294067, 8.00297927856445, 8.00735855102539, 
8.0117359161377, 8.01611709594727, 8.02049446105957, 8.02487277984619, 
8.02925491333008, 8.03363132476807, 8.038010597229, 8.04239177703857, 
8.04676914215088, 8.05114841461182, 8.05552768707275, 8.05990695953369, 
8.06428337097167, 8.06866455078125, 8.07304191589355, 8.07742118835449, 
8.08180236816406, 8.08617973327637, 8.0905590057373, 8.09494018554688, 
8.09931659698486, 8.1036958694458, 8.10807704925537, 8.11245441436768, 
8.11683368682861, 8.12121295928955, 8.12559032440186, 8.12996959686279, 
8.13435077667236, 8.13872718811035, 8.14310646057129, 8.14748764038085, 
8.15186500549316, 8.1562442779541, 8.16062545776367, 8.16500282287598, 
8.16937923431396, 8.17376136779785, 8.17813777923583, 8.18251705169678, 
8.18689823150635, 8.19127559661865, 8.19565486907958, 8.20003604888916, 
8.20441341400146, 8.20879173278809, 8.21317386627197, 8.21755027770996, 
8.2219295501709, 8.22630882263184, 8.23068618774414, 8.23506546020508, 
8.23944664001465, 8.24382305145264, 8.24820232391357, 8.25258350372314, 
8.25696086883544, 8.26134014129639, 8.26572132110596, 8.27009868621826, 
8.27447795867919, 8.27885723114014, 8.28323554992676, 8.28761291503906, 
8.29199409484863, 8.29637145996094, 8.30075073242188, 8.30513191223145, 
8.30950927734375, 8.31388854980469, 8.31826972961426, 8.32264614105225, 
8.32702541351318, 8.33140659332275, 8.33578395843506, 8.340163230896, 
8.34454250335693, 8.34891986846924, 8.35329818725585, 8.35768032073975, 
8.36205673217773, 8.36643600463867, 8.37081718444824, 8.37519454956055, 
8.37957382202148, 8.38395500183105, 8.38833236694335, 8.39271068572998, 
8.39708995819092, 8.40146923065186, 8.40584659576416, 8.41022777557373, 
8.41460514068604, 8.41898441314697, 8.42336559295654, 8.42774295806885, 
8.43212127685547, 8.43650245666504, 8.44087982177734, 8.44525909423828, 
8.44963836669922, 8.45401763916016, 8.45839500427246, 8.46277618408203, 
8.46715259552001, 8.47153186798096, 8.47591304779053, 8.48029041290283, 
8.48466968536376, 8.48905086517333, 8.49342823028564, 8.49780750274658, 
8.50218677520751, 8.50656509399414, 8.51094245910645, 8.51532363891602, 
8.51970100402832, 8.52408027648926, 8.52846145629883, 8.53283882141113, 
8.53721714019775, 8.54159927368164, 8.54597568511963, 8.55035495758057, 
8.5547342300415, 8.55911350250244, 8.56349086761475, 8.56787204742432, 
8.5722484588623, 8.57662773132324, 8.58100891113281, 8.58538627624512, 
8.58976554870605, 8.59414672851563, 8.59852409362792, 8.60290336608887, 
8.60728454589844, 8.61166095733643, 8.61604022979736, 8.6204195022583, 
8.62479686737061, 8.62917613983154, 8.63355731964111, 8.63793468475342, 
8.64231395721436, 8.64669513702393, 8.65107154846191, 8.65545082092285, 
8.65983200073242, 8.66420936584473, 8.66858863830566, 8.6729679107666, 
8.67734718322754, 8.68172359466553, 8.68610572814941, 8.6904821395874, 
8.69486141204833, 8.69924259185791, 8.70361995697021)
```

These are the functions to create a gauss profile, calculate the root mean square error and optimize the three parameters for the the Gauss profile:

```
GaussCurve <- function(rt.Vector,par) #generate Gauss profile
{
  m <- par[1]
  sd <- par[2]
  k <- par[3]
  Fct.V <- k * exp(-0.5 * ((rt.Vector - m)/sd)^2)
  Fct.V
}

RMSE <- function(par) #calculate root mean square error
{ 
  Fct.V <- GaussCurve(rt,par)
  sqrt(sum((signal - Fct.V)^2)/length(signal))
}

signal <- y
rt <- x

#optimization 
result <- optim(c(rt[which.max(signal)], unname(quantile(rt)[4]-quantile(rt)[2]), max(signal)), 
                lower = c(min(rt), -Inf, 0.1*max(signal)),
                upper = c(max(rt), Inf, max(signal)),
                RMSE, method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(factr=1e7))
result 


#plot of result
plot(rt,signal,xlab="RT/min",ylab="I")
lines(seq(min(rt),max(rt),length=1000),GaussCurve(seq(min(rt),max(rt),length=1000),result$par),col=2)
```

When I use this code I get now some result which is of course a bad fit as I would expect for those data.
However, when I run the same code with

```
    signal <- y/max(y)
```

The fit looks totally different. Why is that? I know that I can't get a good fit with those data but from my understanding of the optimization process I would have expected to get the same fit in both cases. 
Am I trapped in a local minimum in one of the cases? This would not be a problem in this case as the fit is bad anyway, but I want to be sure that it does not happen in cases where the fit would have been valid.
So can I adapt anythin in my code to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a few suggestions from my experience:

- find a better target function
- try and make your function as "smooth" (with respect to parameters) as possible.  adding an error term can help here
- prefer likelihood based approaches over RMSE, I've rarely found the latter useful
- try and make your function as "smooth" (with respect to parameters) as possible.  I'd add an "error" parameter
- transform parameters as needed rather than passing limits to `optim`

combining a couple of these, I'd have your target function doing:

```
optfn <- function(par) {
    Fct.V <- GaussCurve(rt,par)
    se2 <- exp(par[4])
    -sum(dnorm(signal, Fct.V, se2, log=TRUE))
}

result <- optim(c(
    rt[which.max(signal)],
    quantile(rt)[[4]] - quantile(rt)[[2]],
    max(signal) * 0.7,
    log(max(signal) * 0.7)
), optfn)
```

and which helps a bit, but not much.

a [Monte-carlo approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) gives me much better results, I get 95% CIs of `8.248 <= par[0] <= 8.276` and `0.170 <= par[1] <= 0.205`.  when I do your `y/max(y)` transform I get `8.249 <= par[0] <= 8.275` and `0.171 <= par[1] <= 0.204`, which seems appropriately consistent.  it's much more complicated though, so depends how much you want to spend learning

Comment: I was trying to find out what you mean by "error parameter"? I can see that you added this se2 therm but I dont really understand how it works or why you chose it to be exp(par[4]).

Comment: it's a standard deviation so needs to be strictly positive (hence the `exp`) and you've used the first three parameters, so hence it's number 4. it's about keeping the function "smooth", and without something like it I've noticed that optimisation tends to get "stuck" in local-minima more often.  thinking about it now, it's just something I tend to put in models like this without much thought — I'd be interested if it doesn't help in the general case

Comment: So it is actually performing some kind of smoothing when I use an error function? Could I then instead just use somthing like like Savitzky Golay before doing the fit?

Comment: I meant smooth in that derivatives are all continuous